# Is there any way to specify the JDK version to be used for compiling dependent projects in maven?

Tags: java, maven

I am having a multi module maven project (here's the [Project strucure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCjo9.png)) in which there are some modules (module1, module2, module3) and both Module 1 and 2 has dependency on Module 3

Currently, I am using toolchains to compile the module 1 with JDK 8 and module 2 with JDK 11.
Now, What I want to achieve here is, when I build the project through the parent POM , I want

1. Module 3 to be compiled with JDK 8 for Module 1
2. Module 3 to be compiled with JDK 11 for Module 2

Is there any way to specify the JDK version for building the dependencies? Or any other workaround that would let me compile the dependent projects with different JDK?

Comment: Use JDK 11 and use `--release 8` for one module (maven-compiler-plugin configuration) and `--release 11` for another module...if you compile module 3 with JDK 11 (release 8) you can use it as a dependency in both cases....

Comment: You can use -source and -target options for each module - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: source/target is not enough for building with JDK 11 to  8...

Comment: @khmarbaise The default JAVA_HOME is fixed to JDK8, because of which I used toolchains.

Comment: As I said do not use toolchain because using JDK 11 with `--release 8` (`<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>`) option is much better...furthermore it makes your configuration easier...apart from that I would suggest to migrate fully to JDK 11 only...I don't understand why you have one module in JDK 8 ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't have permission to change the JAVA_HOME, I can only make changes to module2 and module 3

Comment: That does not make sense because you are using toolchains which exactly does that..in the end.

Comment: Then ask for permission to change JAVA_HOME. There must be somebody could give you permission.

Comment: As a possible hack, I guess you can change/override JAVA_HOME for current terminal before running maven build